# Mapping two mapping tables together?

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database

[image: database design]

I am trying do design a complex database and I have a few questions.

1: Is it wrong in any way to map two mapping tables together? Regardless of the reason, I am trying to find out if it's against normalization or best practices.

2: How can I improve, or avoid mapping two mapping tables together like in the attached image?

Rules:

`Course` - contains every course (training that we do)

Courses can be of more types, types are stored in `courseType` table

Courses will always have people which are of more types (stored in `people` table), each of these people will have a role (roles are stored in `role` table.

Some courses will accept only some types of roles, that's why i did the `courseTypes_has_roles` table.

`people_has_role` table is mapped so that I can see which `people` can be which `role` for which `course` type.

`course_has_people_has_roles` is mapping which `people` are assigned with which `role` for every `course`. It's very important to know that some people can have more roles for a type of course, but they will have only one of them for each separate course.

Things i'm trying to avoid: I don't want to specify what role has each person in the `course` table because there will be people who are assigned roles but they don't belong to any course yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your design. Course_has_people_has_roles seem to mean "person P is assigned role R for course C" and People_has_role seems to mean "person P may be assigned role R". These are two relationships which cannot be derived from each other. But every P-R subrow in the former must appear in the latter, so there is a foreign key from the former to the latter on {P,R}.

*PS* Your use of "map" is odd. (Although "relationship" is misused similarly by many conventional methods & tools.) Those arrows are foreign keys. A foreign key holds when subrow values for a column set must appear as subrowvalues for another column set. In ER-style diagrams they typically are foreign keys to entity ids in entity tables or sets of entity ids in other relationship/association tables. Application relationships/associations (n-way "mappings") are represented by *tables*. If that condition holds, just say so by putting in the arrow. If you want to record an application relationship, make a relationship/association/table. If you can express some in terms of others, *then* you don't need them all.

*PPS* "Has" doesn't mean anything. It's says some things are related/associated. Of course they're related, any number of things are related in any number of ways. *Which* way?  Using "Has" in a table name is like using "Flag" in the name of a boolean variable or "Count" in the name of an integer variable. Compare to boolean "Poisons" or integral "ThousandsOfVoltsAC". A table holds the rows that make some parameterized statement--*predicate*--true. It represents an application relationship/association. Use its predicate to name the *particular* (among *endless*) relationship/association it represents.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really just learning this stuff, so I didn't understand everything explained, but I'm glad that the logic of the database structure is ok. I'm still working on it and learning in the meantime.